# Plotting a line y = aX^b with known a and b parameters

Tags: r, data-visualization

I found the parameters a and b of the above equation by fitting a linear model to `log(y) = log(a) + b*log(X)`. I am wanting to back transform the model into a non-linear plot of the line following the equation `y = aX^b` using R software. I understand there are functions in R to fit a model (e.g., `nls()`), however, I am not interested in fitting a non-linear model I only want to plot the non-linear line that was found using the log-log transformation. Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fully parameterized equation, you just need to make a vector of the domain you want to view (the X values), directly compute the Y values, and plot them.

```
a=1; b=2;
x = seq(-10, 10, 0.1)
y = a*(x^b)
plot(x,y)
```

Comment: Well looks like I was way overthinking this problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
f <- function(x) a * x^b
curve(f, -10, 10)
```

and you will see

[image]